# How prove this inequality $(a^3+b^3+c^3)(ab+bc+ac)\ge 6abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c$ are postive numbers, show that

> $$(a^3+b^3+c^3)(ab+bc+ac)\ge 6abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$$

my try: let
$$a+b+c=p,ab+bc+ac=q,abc=r$$
and the
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(ab+bc+ac)(a+b+c)=p^3-3pq$$

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that:
$$
(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc= (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)
$$
Therefore it is enough to prove that
$$
(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac)\ge 6abc
$$
This is done as follows:
$$
(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac)\ge 3(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\times 3(abc)^{\frac{2}{3}}=9abc \geq 6abc.
$$

Comment: Nice.if $a,b,c$ are real numbers,then my inequality is true? Thank you

Comment: ,Thank you, I fonud maybe is true,and Now if $a,b,c$ are real numbers,How prove it?

Comment: But mean that don't use $AM-GM$

Comment: $a=b=c=-1$, LHS$=-9$,RHS$=0$,so it is not true for all real.

Comment: Since it is an inequality between two fifth-degree homogeneous polynomials, if it holds for a certain triple $(a,b,c)$ then it holds in the opposite direction for $(-a,-b,-c)$!